# Navigation not displaying in Omega 4 subtheme

Tags: navigation, theming

I have made an Omega 4 subtheme cloned from the omega default starterkit using drush. I made a layout template based on /sites/all/themes/omega/omega/templates/system/page.tpl.php, and selected it. 
The template documents the following for region content:

```
   $page['branding']: Items for the branding region. 
   $page['header']: Items for the header region. 
   $page['navigation']: Items for the navigation region. 
   $page['help']: Dynamic help text, mostly for admin pages. 
   $page['highlighted']: Items for the highlighted content region. 
   $page['content']: The main content of the current page.
   $page['sidebar_first']: Items for the first sidebar.
   $page['sidebar_second']: Items for the second sidebar.
   $page['footer']: Items for the footer region.
```

However, $page['navigation'] does not have any content for any of my pages, so the navigation is not rendering here:
    `<`?php print render($page['navigation']); ?>

My pages all have "Provide a menu link" checked, and the navigation region is enabled in my layout.inc file.

I am new to Omega 4 - what am I missing?

One thing I have found is that $main_menu does have the menu items set as an array - am I supposed to populate $page['navigation'] myself from $main_menu in layout.preprocess.inc?

I'd be grateful for any help.

Comment: Is the main navigation block placed in a region?

Comment: No, it wasn't! <blushes> That fixed it, thank you.